# not enough items save and drag and drop not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

i downloaded not enough items to my mods folder along with code chicken and it shows up when i check my inventory but all my save buttons are not there, and i can not drag nothing to my inventory, i will show you a picture of what im getting, if anyone could help and give me advice on what i need to do to get it showing up properly and being able to drag and drop would be awesome

also i almost forgot to mention, the save tabs work in my creative mode but not in survival

[image: this is how it shows for me on my screen]

Comment: Cheat mode is disabled by default in survival worlds. You'll need to dive into the configs a little to change that.

Comment: Click the little options button down in the button left corner, and change it from Utility/Recipe to Cheat.